# System.Configuration in Mono mobile profile (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: mono, xamarin.android

Why is it missing? How do you store application settings?

Comment: Maybe [PCLAppConfig](https://github.com/soroshsabz/PCLAppConfig) help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Shared Preferences in Android.